# ServiceNow Rest API OAuth returns not Authorized error

Tags: api, integration, servicenow

I managed to access the Rest Api with Basic authentication with username and password.
Now I am trying to access the Rest Api with OAuth.
I was referring to [this article](http://http//wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=Generating_OAuth_Tokens#API_Request_Parameters&gsc.tab=0)

This is the format of the POST message I created (using Postman with Chrome),

```
POST /oauth_token.do HTTP/1.1
Host: devxxxxx.service-now.com
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46Q0BycjBsMTIz
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Url Encoded body:

```
grant_type=password&client_id=xxxxxx&client_secret=xxxxxx&username=admin&username=xxxxxx
```

I tried both encoded body and body without encoding, it gives the same result.

Response

```
{
    "error": "server_error",
    "error_description": "access_denied"
}
```

Am I missing something here? Doesn't the "admin" user has privileges to perform this operation and acquire tokens?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, two things,

1. Mistake (typed username twice in the body instead of password)

grant_type=password&client_id=xxxxxx&client_secret=xxxxxx&username=admin&username=xxxxxx

SHOULD BE,

grant_type=password&client_id=xxxxxx&client_secret=xxxxxx&username=admin&password=xxxxxx

2. For this request you should not have the Authorization Header. I removed the Basic Authorization header. it's working now.

**Recap,**

Using POSTMAN,

Make sure the endpoint is "https://[instance-now].com/oauth_token.do "

Headers: 
Accept: application/json

Body (x-www-form-urlencoded)

grant_type : password
client_id: xxxxxx
client_secret: xxxxxxx
username: username_01
password: password_01

Hope this will help someone....